# Is this a standard AlertDialog or is it custom?

Tags: android

I'm looking to replicate and improve upon the following `AlertDialog` in my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU3Ep.png

Is this a built-in `AlertDialog`, or was this made from scratch? If it was made from scratch, what control/widget is the number picker? Or is that built from scratch too?

Thanks!

btw.. screenshot is from Math Alarm Clock Pro

Comment: You can add a custom view to an alertdialog. You can also apply the dialog theme to any activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like custom dialog made like explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Kind of looks similar to this one:
http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

So that would mean: custom made.

You find some interesting links if you search on google for "android NumberPicker"

Built in Dialogs are AlertDialog, DatePickerDialog, ProgressDialog, TimePickerDialog (see developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html )

This explains the default AlertDialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

But there is one interesting function in AlertDialog (setView(...)) you could use to make the above (but you have to create the view by yourself - edittext and two buttons plus okay button - and assign the onclickevents). See the function here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View)

Comment: Thanks! I found that link too once I knew what to search for :)

Answer (score 0):

Just looks like a standard dialog set to have no title. It then has an EditText sandwiched between two buttons with a confirmation button at the bottom.

Edit: Here is an abridged snippet from my onCreateDialog override in an app of mine.

```
Dialog dialog;
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: don't think that is possible. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: Built in AlertDialogs are AlertDialog, DatePickerDialog, ProgressDialog, TimePickerDialog (see  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html )

Comment: It can be done using: dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: I did manage to find this.. and it does appear to work.. http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5